# Why is the "20% battery" message box crashing my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I work on a ipod apps, and when I run it on a real device, my apps crash when the msgbox 20$% battery left. How I can fix that? I think this msgbox stop one of my thread(a timer), is it possible?

Comment: If you gave us even part of your code, this would actually be a question. Right now, it looks like "I have a bug in my application, can you tell me how to fix it?". If you can't provide us with any more details, I'm afraid you won't have much scope in getting your question answered, and your question will probably closed.

Comment: I agree with Dhaivat, you need to gather more information about this bug before anyone can help you. Look over the crash logs, debug your app while connected and drop the battery % to below 20%, and try to figure out what is crashing.

Answer (score 3):

Does the same thing happen when the device receives a phone call, SMS, or push notification? If so, it's probably something in your app delegate’s `-application:willResignActive:` method. Check your code in there, or—better yet—update your question to include that code.

Comment: Or it could be `applicationDidBecomeActive:`